# Unable to change variable from anonymous class

Tags: java, android, retrofit, anonymous

I'm fairly new to Java and Android Development. I'm trying to make an app for my website. I'm using `Retrofit` to connect to my REST web service.

The following is a piece of code that I'm using to iterate through the ids of the customer and for each id, a call is made to retrieve the email associated with the id. `authenticateUser` method receives the username, the password and the list of ids(Customer ids). The ids are located at mywebsite/api/customers.
The emails are available at mywebsite/api/customers/id

```
public class Authentication {

    private static String receivedEmail;
    public static boolean authenticateUser(List<Integer> ids, final String username, String pass) {
        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(MainActivity.ENDPOINT).build();
        AuthenticationUsernameAPI api = adapter.create(AuthenticationUsernameAPI.class);
        final boolean[] found = {false};
        for (Integer id: ids) {
            if (!found[0]) {
                api.getUserEmail(id.toString(), new Callback<CustomerLoginEmail>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(CustomerLoginEmail customerLoginEmail, Response response) {
                        receivedEmail = customerLoginEmail.getCustomer().getEmail().toString();
                        if (receivedEmail.compareTo(username) == 0) {                        
                            found[0] = true;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                        Log.d("ERROR", error.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }    
}
```

The method `authenticateUser` **always** returns false. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was pretty obvious and easy but since I'm new to all this(or maybe I'm stupid :p), it took me quite some time.

I used Retrofit's SYNCHRONOUS call. The interface:

```
@GET("/user/{id}")
UserObject getUser(@Path("id") int id);
```

and I called it inside AsyncTask like this:

```
UserObject user = api.getUser();
```

Hope this helps any other newbies like me

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the loop registers callbacks and doesn't wait for them to finish, so it also doesn't wait to check if the callbacks were actually called. Since the callbacks didn't complete in time, they had no chance to change `found[0]` to `true` before it was checked by the `if` condition.

You should refactor the code, so it waits for each callback to complete.